# Logos slightly higher than text in script for HTML Signature

Tags: html, outlook

I've got my script for our company signature pretty much ready to go, except that the social media logo is slightly higher than the text it is next to. I don't really script very often, and some of this I ripped from another script, so I don't know how to fix this. The particular code in question is below:

```
CreateSigFile.WriteLine "<td background='logo location' bgcolor='#7bceeb' width='170' height='38.4' valign='top' position='absolute'><!--[if gte mso 9]><v:rect xmlns:v='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml' fill='true' stroke='false' style='width:510px;height:38.4px;position:absolute;'><v:fill type='tile' src='c:\tey_sig_logos\bar.png' color='#7bceeb' /><v:textbox inset='0,0,0,0'><![endif]--><div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span><a href="& "company url"& """ target="& """_blank"& """ rel="& """noopener"& """ style="& """text-decoration:none;"& """><span style="& """font-size: 12pt; font-family: Jabara, sans-serif; color: #A9A49B;"& """>company url</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>"
CreateSigFile.WriteLine "<span><a href="& strFacebook & """ target="& """_blank"& """ rel="& """noopener"& """><img style='float: right' padding='0px 0px 0px 3px' img border='0' alt='Logo' width='110.4' height='auto' src='" & strFacebook & "' style='margin-bottom: -7'></a></span>"
CreateSigFile.WriteLine "</div><!--[if gte mso 9]></v:textbox></v:rect><![endif]--></td>"
```

Anyone have any ideas?

I've tried adding padding and margining to the logo, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. This is really not my world, I'm a System and Network Admin, so any help would be appreciated!